# Selecting main class in a runnable jar at runtime

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I have two main classes in the app. When I package it to a runnable jar (using Eclipse export function) I have to select a default main class.

Is there a way to access the non-default main class from the jar at runtime?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can access both via `java -cp myapp.jar com.example.Main1` and `java -cp myapp.jar com.example.Main2`. The default main class in the jar is for when you invoke your app via `java -jar myapp.jar`.

See [JAR_(file_format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)) for more details. When you select the main class in Eclipse this is what gets set in: `Main-Class: myPrograms.MyClass` inside of the jar manifest `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` in side of the jar file.

Comment: This won't work with the Eclipse Runnable export as they delegate loading to a custom classloader.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's possible. You can under each add another class with a main method for that which executes the desired class/method based on the argument.

E.g.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    if ("foo".equals(args[0])) {
        Foo.main(args);
    } else if ("bar".equals(args[0])) {
        Bar.main(args);
    }
 }
```

(don't forget to add the obvious checks yourself such as `args.length` and so on)

Which you can use as follows:

```
java -jar YourJar.jar foo
```

If well designed, this can however make the `main()` method of the other classes superfluous. E.g.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    if ("foo".equals(args[0])) {
        new Foo().execute();
    } else if ("bar".equals(args[0])) {
        new Bar().execute();
    }
 }
```

To abstract this more (to get rid of if/else blocks), you could consider to let them implement some `Action` interface with a `void execute()` and get hold of them in a `Map`:

```
private static Map<String, Action> actions = new HashMap<String, Action>();
static {
    actions.put("foo", new Foo());
    actions.put("bar", new Bar());
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    actions.get(args[0]).execute();
}
```