# I am making software in java. Tell me how to convert .java file to .jar file that can be runnable

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting main class in a runnable jar at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023506/selecting-main-class-in-a-runnable-jar-at-runtime)

Help me to convert .java file to .jar

Answer (score 3):

use [jar](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html) command

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert java to jar file. You can, however, build a jar file with the [`jar`](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html) command or use a build tool, like [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) to create a jar (or use an IDE to export as jar).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it "runnable", you also want to specify the Main-Class and the Class-Path in the Manifest file:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html